# What are the ranges of these negations?

Tags: negation

> Days later. A week. Two. I don’t know. After Denny’s deflation, time meant little to me; he looked sickly, he had no energy, no life force, and so neither did I. At a point when my hips still bothered me––***not*** so long as to have healed [i], ***not*** so soon that the pain was acute [ii]––we went to visit Mike and Tony.
>   (Garth Stein, The Art of Racing in the Rain)

It seems like the first negation is applied on to *so long* (partially); the second on to *so soon that the pain was acute* (wholly). Is my guessing right or am I to see other ways? If mine is okay, what factor causes the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it exactly right.

```
     pain acute to here→|                                              |←hips healed here
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
                    ↑↑↑↑↑ not so soon as here   ,  not so long as here ↑↑↑↑↑  
=                       |←------------(somewhere in here)-------------→|
```

Comment: MY curiosity is  whether this –– when the indirect complement for ‘so’ is ‘degree’ as in [i], the negation applies partially, and when it is ‘result’ as in [ii], the negation does wholly –– could be a general application or not.

Comment: @Listenever Ah ... perhaps you are thinking that *so long **as*** and *so soon **that*** are contrasted here? If that's the case, the author has misled you: the **as** belongs to *as to have* = *that it had*, not to a comparative *so long as*. Both *sos* may be expressed by *so ADV that STATE*: not so long that my hips had healed, not so short that my pain was still acute.